# Angular how to wait until a long text is fully displayed?

Tags: angular, typescript, wait

my problem is I want to display a text, if it was short there would be no problems, but when the text gets too long it would jump some sentences. so I need to add a wait time until it is printed out correctly but I don't know how since I am new in Angular and TypeScript.
I have read about `setTimeout` but don't know how to implement it into the section that I need it in.
`<p>{{longText}}</p>`

and if it is possible to give explanation as much as possible.

Comment: show us the tried code

Comment: Please share the code snippet...

Comment: and `setTimeout` - *The setTimeout() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin (and successor to Window.setTimeout()) sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires.* to display anything - it will not help you!

Comment: How long the text is? From where you are fetching it?

Comment: haven't tried anything sine I don't know how it works

Comment: @SHA then where you used `setTimeout`?

Comment: I am fetching it from a backend that will get it from the database, and the data is over 6000 in length

Comment: I just read about it never used it

Comment: @SHA Then you have to try it, test it if something not working then let us know!

Comment: have tried ```<p>{{delay(5000)}}</p>``` and in the ```.ts``` file ```delay(time: number){ return setTimeout( () => this.data, time); }``` now it returns a bunch of numbers that keeps increasing and giving a lot of errors on the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this.

The following demo renders 5000 rows of data;

[Live demo - load table](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x7buas?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

The following demo renders data >5 MB of data.

[Live demo - load string data](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zgekxu?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

ts

```
  isLoading = false;
  data;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  loadData() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos').subscribe(
      (res) => { this.data = res; },
      (err) => {},
      () => { this.isLoading = false; }
    )
  }
```

html

```
<p *ngIf="isLoading">Loading..</p>

<table style="width:100%" *ngIf="data && !isLoading">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let val of data">
    <td>{{val.id}}</td>
    <td>{{val.title}}</td>
    <td>{{val.url}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to share the data?

Comment: no, sorry. and the problem is with a String type not an object

Comment: Okay. I ll try with online sample data.

Comment: btw I made a mistake the string is over 30000 characters

Comment: Try second demo, where I'm rendering >5MB data which is >8 Lakh characters.

Comment: can you explain this section ```res = JSON.stringify(res);```, thank you in advance

Comment: *res + res* is just a string concatenation to have large data sample. *<p> res </p>* is HTML content. Inspect it, you'll understand. [Ref](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: yes figured that when I looked at it again, thank you it worked liked a charm and it is better to use ```innerText``` instead so you can add classes to the element, thank you again and sorry for the trouble

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203030/discussion-between-sh-a-and-hbamithkumara).

Answer (score 0):

As per the async call behavior, first the data will be resolved and then only the view gets updated. Of course, your template should be bound with `*ngIf` conditions properly.

I have updated the code, shared by @hbamithkumara.

I think 
The loader is a nice addon for the user feedback purpose but the basic thing that you want to understand here is to load a `{{longText}}` (long text/data).

**Template**

```
<td>{{val?.id}}</td>
<td>{{val?.title}}</td>
<td>{{val?.url}}</td>
```

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';;
  data;
  loading = true;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos').subscribe( res => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.data = res;
    })
  }

}
```

- DEMO (preview): https://sof-q-59029627.stackblitz.io/
- DEMO (edit): https://stackblitz.com/edit/sof-q-59029627